# Rails always routes an action to show action, and the action it self becomes the id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There's a strange behavior in rails I found recently related to routes and actions, specifically, it's on *rails 2.3.5*. I have a controller, let's call it Users. In the routes, I declare Users as a resources.

```
map.resources :users
```

And within the controller, I have the standard action: `index, show, edit, update & destroy`. Also, I added other action to fullfil certain requirements.

```
def generated_pdf_report
    # do something
end
```

The problem is, when I go to page `/users/generated_pdf_report`, I get this on the console:

```
Processing UsersController#show (some timestamps) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"generated_pdf_report", "controller"=>"users"}
```

As you can see, the server route the request to method `show` rather than to method `generated_pdf_report`. ***What's interesting***, is that I have other controllers having similar action and is working fine.

The solution to the above problem is easy enough, make sure the added feed is above the resources:

```
map.feed 'users/generated_pdf_report', :controller => 'users', :action => 'generated_pdf_report'
map.resources :users
```

***My question is***: Anyone knows why rails behaves like that? The above solution is kind of sloppy, what do you think the best practices for such problem like one mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the Rails 2 [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions), you can add collection routes like so:

```
map.resources :users, :collection => { :generated_pdf_report => :get }
```

Answer (score 0):

When rails looks at

```
/users/generate_report
```

That is exactly the path it would use to show a user whose id was generate_report, so that is what it does, assuming you haven't told it otherwise.

A shorter alternative to what you wrote is

```
resources :users, :collection => {:generate_report => :get}
```

Which tells rails to map a GET to /users/generate_report to your generate_report action